# How to apply auto layout to a group of items in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, user-interface

For example, I add one label and two text fields to the main view. After that, I want *this group* of items to be centered horizontally. That is, the center of this group is on the center of the superview. How to achieve that with Xcode or programmingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here steps for you
1. Add all your subviews to container
[image]

2. Add constraints inside container for you labels and textfields
3. Add width / height constraint for container
4. Align horisontally
   [image]
5. Constraints should look like
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Add all these views into a new view, and center that using AL.